# ¿Como filtrar los campos de un buscador en JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, html

> Tengo una tengo una tabla normal que muestra datos desde mi BD y trato
> de implementarle un buscador/filtro (en JavaScript), este funciona
> para buscar en los campos pero para los campos Clase y Proyecto (que
> son foráneos) de otras entidades, no funciona.

**Mi tabla:**

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

**Mi JavaScript:**

```
<script>
  $(document).ready(function(){
    $("#search_casa").keyup(function(){
    
    let mensaje = document.getElementById("tabla_mensaje");
  mostrar(mensaje);
  _this = this;

  $.each($("#tabla_casa tbody tr"), function() {
    if($(this).text().toLowerCase().indexOf($(_this).val().toLowerCase()) !== -1)
    {
        $(this).show();
        ocultar(mensaje);
    }
      else  
    {
        $(this).hide();
    }
    
  });
  
});
});

function mostrar(mensaje)
  {
    mensaje.removeAttribute("hidden");
}
 function ocultar(mensaje)
{
    mensaje.setAttribute("hidden", "hidden");

}    
</script>
```

**Mi error:** Busca en todos los campos, menos en ese, que es el foraneo de la BD

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

**ESTUVE PROBANDO Y CREO QUE EL ERROR NO ES SYMFONY, SI NO MI BUSCADOR/FILTRO, PERO NO SE DONDE PUEDE ESTAR EL ERROR**

Comment: Con una imagen es imposible probar tu código. Por favor, edita la pregunta y pon el codigo en texto para que los que quieran probarlo no lo tengan que escribir todo a mano. Yo en el each del javascript, pondría un console.log para ver que datos hai y comprobar por que no filtra

Comment: @Suso la cosa es que no puedo poner mas codigo, de ponerlo, me pide que rellene con mas imagenes XD

Comment: @Marcos No se ve, pero mas abajo de la tabla, tengo esto

                <table id="tabla_mensaje" style="text-align: center;" class="table table-striped" hidden>
                  <tr>
                    <td>No se encontraron resutados</td>
                  </tr>
                </table>

Que tiene un mensaje por si no encuentra nada